# unable to run scenario outline example of cucumber file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am learing cucumber. While trying to execute cucumber scenario outline I am getting error. Following is the cucumber feature file

```
Feature: to test pages titles    
Scenario Outline: to check title of the mutliple pages
Given Open the browser
When navigate to <Link> page
Then check <Title> of the page
Then close the browser

Examples: 
  | Link                     | Title                  |
  | https://cucumber.io/     | Cucumber               |
  | https://cucumber.io/docs | Documentation·Cucumber |
  | https://cucumber.io/blog | Blog·Cucumber          |
```

Following is the step defination of the cucumber file

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class scenario_outline_sd 
{
static WebDriver driver;
@Given("^Open the browser$")
public void open_the_browser() throws Throwable 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium bwosers\\chrome 2.35\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@When("^navigate to \"([^\"]*)\" page$")
public void navigate_to_page(String page) throws Throwable 
{
    driver.get(page);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Then("^check \"([^\"]*)\" of the page$")
public void check_title_of_the_page(String title) throws Throwable 
{
    if(driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title))
    {
        System.out.println("Verified title of : "+title);
    }
}

@Then("^close the browser$")
public void close_the_browser() throws Throwable 
{
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

while running cuucmber feature file it is opening browser 3 times but not taking parameter of URL. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you give an error regexp in step definition.

There is no double quota around step argument in feature steps:

[image]

But you use double quota in regexp in step definition:

[image]

Remove `\"` as below should work

```
@When("^navigate to ([^\"]*) page$")
public void navigate_to_page(String page) throws Throwable 
{
    System.out.println(page);
    driver.get(page);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Then("^check ([^\"]*) of the page$")
public void check_title_of_the_page(String title) throws Throwable 
{
    System.out.println(title);
    if(driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title))
    {
        System.out.println("Verified title of : "+title);
    }
}
```

I can run it on my local with below practice code: 
**feature file:** 
[image]

**step defintion and run result:** 
[image]

Comment: hi yong, by removing \" in stepdefination it is showing NullPointerException on respective mothod. Now it is not accepting Link parameter.

Comment: I guess you not get my point, but to remove the `\"` inside `([^\"]*) `, my point is to remove than the heading and tail `\"` of  `\"([^\"]*)\"`  , see my updated code in above answer

Comment: yes yong, I had tried same thing earlier. By changing the code you have suggested then it is showiing NullPointerException on navigate_to_page method.

Comment: I have no more words how i can help you further, I even writen example code and run it on my local, proved them can work as expect.  The parameter 'Link' and 'Title' obtained and printed out.  Your NullPointException is no matter with getting parameter 'Link' and 'Title' , If the variable  `driver` is null, it's your problem and it's a very very basic issue you should notice and can fix it. Rather than wait others to find out for you.

Comment: hey yong, thank you for providing me a code. Now its working fine at my side by removing "WebDriver" keyword in WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();